# Using a PHP variable to aggregate in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, variables, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've been trying to use PHP Variables to get results from a mongoDB database.

This works:

```
//create Mongo connection
$m = new MongoClient();

//Select db
$db = $m->warehouse;

//create collection
$fact = $db->fact;
$res = $fact->aggregate([
    array(
        '$match'=>array(
            'day'=>array('$gte'=>3,'$lte'=>28),
            'month'=>array('$gte'=>3,'$lte'=>3),
            'year'=>array('$gte'=>2017,'$lte'=>2017)
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group'=>array(
            '_id'=>array(
                'month'=>'$month',
                'day'=>'$day',
                'year'=>'$year'
            ), 
            'totalSales'=>array('$sum'=>'$sale'), 
            'totalCost'=>array('$sum'=>'$total_cost')
        )
    ), 
    array(
        '$project'=>array(
            '_id'=>0,
            'totalSales'=>1,
            'totalCost'=>1,
            'totalProfit'=>array(
                '$subtract'=>['$totalSales','$totalCost']
            )
        )
    )
]);
```

Output of var_dump($res):

```
array (size=3)
'waitedMS' => int 0
'result' => 
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'totalSales' => float 440
      'totalCost' => float 350
      'totalProfit' => float 90
'ok' => float 1
```

But When I try to replace the numbers with php variables like:

```
$res = $fact->aggregate([
    array(
        '$match'=>array(
            'day'=>array('$gte'=>$dayfrom,'$lte'=>$dayto),
            'month'=>array('$gte'=>$monthfrom,'$lte'=>$monthto),
            'year'=>array('$gte'=>$yearfrom,'$lte'=>$yearto)
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group'=>array(
            '_id'=>array(
                'month'=>'$month',
                'day'=>'$day',
                'year'=>'$year'
            ), 
            'totalSales'=>array('$sum'=>'$sale'), 
            'totalCost'=>array('$sum'=>'$total_cost')
        )
    ), 
    array(
        '$project'=>array(
            '_id'=>0,
            'totalSales'=>1,
            'totalCost'=>1,
            'totalProfit'=>array(
                '$subtract'=>['$totalSales','$totalCost']
            )
        )
    )
]);
```

I don't get back any results:

```
array (size=3)
'waitedMS' => int 0
'result' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
'ok' => float 1
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have tried several things like putting the PHP variables under single quotes or trying to put parts of the query into strings and using those strings to re-build the query but nothing seems to work excep for the hard-coded numbers into the aggregation. Any idea what's going on here?

**EDIT: (This did the trick)**
Tried initializing the variables in a PHP class constructor that explicitly specifies that the value is coming from a PHP variable:

```
class DateSet {
public $df;
public $dt;
public $mf;
public $mt;
public $yf;
public $yt;

function __construct( $df, $dt, $mf, $mt, $yf, $yt) {
    $this->df = $df;
    $this->dt = $dt;
    $this->mf = $mf;
    $this->mt = $mt;
    $this->yf = $yf;
    $this->yt = $yt;
}
};

$dateobj = new DateSet($dayfrom,$dayto,$monthfrom,$monthto,$yearfrom,$yearto);

$res = $fact->aggregate([
    array(
        '$match'=>array(
            'day'=>array('$gte'=>$dateobj->df,'$lte'=>$dateobj->dt),
            'month'=>array('$gte'=>$dateobj->mf,'$lte'=>$dateobj->mt),
            'year'=>array('$gte'=>$dateobj->yf,'$lte'=>$dateobj->yt)
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group'=>array(
            '_id'=>array(
                'month'=>'$month',
                'day'=>'$day',
                'year'=>'$year'
            ), 
            'totalSales'=>array('$sum'=>'$sale'), 
            'totalCost'=>array('$sum'=>'$total_cost')
        )
    ), 
    array(
        '$project'=>array(
            '_id'=>0,
            'totalSales'=>1,
            'totalCost'=>1,
            'totalProfit'=>array(
                '$subtract'=>['$totalSales','$totalCost']
            )
        )
    )
]);
```

OUTPUT:

```
array (size=3)
'waitedMS' => int 0
'result' => 
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'totalSales' => float 640
      'totalCost' => float 520
      'totalProfit' => float 120
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'totalSales' => float 8000
      'totalCost' => float 6000
      'totalProfit' => float 2000
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'totalSales' => float 700
      'totalCost' => float 600
      'totalProfit' => float 100
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'totalSales' => float 18000
      'totalCost' => float 15000
      'totalProfit' => float 3000
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'totalSales' => float 6300
      'totalCost' => float 6100
      'totalProfit' => float 200
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'totalSales' => float 68503
      'totalCost' => float 55720
      'totalProfit' => float 12783
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'totalSales' => float 440
      'totalCost' => float 350
      'totalProfit' => float 90
 'ok' => float 1
```

Comment: Are you sure the variables are populated before they are passed to mongodb?

Comment: Can we see how variables are initialized ?

Comment: @PhilippFlenker - Yeah I'm using a PHP form to get input from using datepicker. In order to make sure they are being populated, I'm printing each of the variables and I'm getting printed results but not the result of the query.

Comment: @Veeram - The variables are initialized from the form input. I've even tried to parse them into integers first but nothing seems to work. `if(isset($_POST["dateRangeSubmit"])){
  echo "submit encountered";
    $from = explode("/",$_POST["fromdate"]);
    $to = explode("/",$_POST["todate"]);
    $dayfrom = (int) $from[1];`